# Redirection of URL

Tags: javascript, dom-events, velocity

I have a VM file with the following codes:

UPDATED:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Input Form</title>
    <style>
        #FW{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    function showSelect()
    {
        var post = document.getElementById('post');
        var fwork = document.getElementById('FW');
        
        fwork.style.display = post.selectedIndex == 1 ? 'block' : 'none';
        
    }
    
    function getMeThere(){
            var post = document.getElementById('post');
            var fwork = document.getElementById('frwork');
            if( post.value.toString() == "dpost"){
                document.forms["adform"].action="https://google.com" ;                  
                document.forms["adform"].method="post" ; 
            } 
            else{
                if(fwork.value.toString() == "wap"){
                    document.forms["adform"].action="https://mail.yahoo.com" ;
                    document.forms["adform"].method="post" ; 
                }
                else {
                    document.forms["adform"].action="bbc.co.uk" ;
                    document.forms["adform"].method="post" ; 
                }
            }
            document.forms["adform"].submit() ; 
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="forum" id="adform" >
        <label>Payment Amount:</label>
        <input type = "text" name="paymentAmount" value=""/>
        <label> Reference:</label>
        <input type = "text" name="Reference" value=""/><br />
        <label>Choose post</label><br/>
        <select name="postCode" onchange="showSelect()" id = "post">
          <option value="dpost">Desktop post</option>
          <option value="mpost">Mobile post</option>
        </select><br/>
        <div id = "FW">
            <label>Choose Your Toolkit</label><br/>
            <select name="frwork" id = "frwork">
                <option id=""></option>
                <option id="jqm">jQuery Mobile</option>
                <option id = "wap">Webapp-Net</option>
                <option id = "tst">a Test</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" onclick="getMeThere()"/>           
    </form>
</body>
```

The redirection doesn't work at all, and I can't seem to find the problem. please notice that the URLs are fake, because I could post the real URL due to security issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo? it would work if you changed:

```
document.forms[this].action
```

to

```
document.forms["adform"].action
```

**Edit**

You also have `var fwork = document.getElementById('FW');`then later `fwork.value.toString()` but `FW` is a **DIV** not the `SELECT`.

Change the select to `<select id="frwork" name="frwork">` and read it with `var fwork = document.getElementById('frwork');`

**Edit 2**

Your `fwork.value.toString() == "wap"` will never be true as the only occurence of `"WAP"` is `<option id = "wap">w-Net</option>` which is not a `.value`.

Change the HTML to:

```
        <select name="frwork" id = "frwork">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="jqm">jQuery Mobile</option>
            <option value = "wap">Webapp-Net</option>
            <option value = "tst">a Test</option>
        </select>
```

And to read the selected **value** replace:

```
if (fwork.value.toString() == "wap") {
```

with:

```
if (fwork.options[fwork.selectedIndex].value == "wap") {
```

Comment: it wouldnt help, at first it was document.forms["adform"].action then i changed it to document.forms[this].action and I forgot to putback the way it was.

Comment: Updated post with another prob

Comment: Thank you, it works now, but I am facing another problem. the first redirection works fine, however, for the second id = "jqm" and also for id="wap" it sends me to a same url, in the code I have assigned them with different url. Do you what is the problem??

Comment: oki, give me a sec, because I have to change some of my codes.

Comment: no, it doesnt work, I changed if (fwork.value.toString() == "wap") { to if (fwork.options[fwork.selectedIndex].value == "wap") { but again it redirects me to the same page, as it does when you select "jqm."

Comment: hey man thanks, I was able to solve it, instead of using fwork.options[fwork.selectedIndex].value I used fwork.options[fwork.selectedIndex].id and it worked. YOu help me alot thanks man

Comment: Your welcome. (You can use .value if you change the options to `<option value="jqm"> ...`)